# Portable standard-syntax atomic operations library in C++

Tags: c++, stl, std, atomic

I know that C++11 provides `<atomic>`, but this isn't implemented by any compiler except GCC 4.7. Is anyone aware of a library that follows the standard (i.e, would be interchangeable with `<atomic>` once it becomes more widely available) and works on older versions of gcc/msvc?

Comment: It's also implemented in VC++11 beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Boost.Atomic](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/doc/index.html) library and [Just Thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/).

[Threading Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) also supplies atomics, but they are not totally standard conformant.

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, but I believe that [`just::thread`](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/) would qualify. It's primarily a threading library, but I believe it includes most of the `<atomic>` header.

Comment: It concerns me that they still refer to C++11 as "the upcoming C++ standard".